# Instruction fetch accesses passing locked instructions

Tags: assembly, concurrency, x86, thread-safety, x86-64

The Intel Software Developer's Manual mentions that "instruction fetch and page table accesses can pass locked instructions". What does this mean, and why does it matter?

There's a post that says that many Windows functions begin with a `MOV EDI, EDI` instruction, because it is useful for safe code hooking: it can be atomically replaced with a two-byte relative jump. But if fetch accesses to memory can "pass locked instructions", is it possible for the following to happen?

- cpu 0 atomically replaces a `MOV EDI, EDI` instruction with a relative jump
- cpu 1 "passes the locked instruction", fetching and executing the stale `MOV EDI, EDI`

Would it also be possible for something like this happen?

- cpu 0 atomically replaces a `MOV EDI, EDI` instruction with a relative jump
- because instruction fetches can "pass the locked instructions", the replacement of the instruction can be considered non-atomic from the context of instruction fetches, so cpu 1 fetches 1 byte from the stale instruction and 1 byte from the new instruction

From Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual, Volume 3: "System Programming Guide"

> Locked operations are atomic with respect to all other memory
>   operations and all externally visible events. **Only instruction fetch
>   and page table accesses can pass locked instructions**. Locked
>   instructions can be used to synchronize data written by one processor
>   and read by another processor.
>
> For the P6 family processors, locked operations serialize all
>   outstanding load and store operations (that is, wait for them to
>   complete). This rule is also true for the Pentium 4 and Intel Xeon
>   processors, with one exception. Load operations that reference weakly
>   ordered memory types (such as the WC memory type) may not be
>   serialized.

Link: [Why do Windows functions all begin with a pointless MOV EDI, EDI instruction?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/09/21/10214405.aspx)

Comment: I'm not sure how the different statements in your question fit together. Here's what I think matters: 1. You want to be able to insert a two-byte jump instruction. 2. The place where you insert that instruction also has to be a two-byte instruction; it cannot, say, be two consecutive, one-byte NOPs, because execution might have executed the first one-byte instruction just before you overwrite the instructions and then fetch a torn second half. Locked memory access doesn't seem to have anything to do with this.

Comment: It's quite clear why instruction fetches and page walks were excluded from having to serialize, it would make them too slow and force the CPU to add expensive hardware to compare their addresses against buffered stores. On the other hand, they're not critical to protect in most multithreading scenarios

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Kerrek SB. I updated the question in an attempt to make it more clear what I'm wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the second scenario - "passing a locked instruction" doesn't mean it breaks atomicity. If the store atomically writes these 2 instruction bytes, you can't see only one of them at any point (the store would simply operate on the full cacheline - note that it won't be atomic if the 2 bytes are split over 2 lines). What it does mean is that any lock instruction you put in order to try synchronizing would not block the code fetch, so in terms of memory ordering - it can occur before or after it.

Now, regarding the first scenario and the question in general - note that there's no lock in your description. The case you describe is perfectly valid even if it were a data read instead of code read - there's no inherent order between the two cores other than what you enforce yourself. In order to enforce such order, you could start working with barriers and semaphores, or any other method, and it would eventually boil down to some lock blocking cpu 1 until cpu 0 signals that the write is done.

In that case, a data read would have been stalled by the lock, but a younger code read could actually fetch the old data in spite of your attempt to protect it. However, here comes a mechanism x86 cores usually implement called SMC (self-modifying code) flush - the store from cpu 0 snoops the instruction cache in cpu 1, detects the stale code there, and since it can't tell where exactly this code is along the pipe, or what effects is may have incurred already (for all we know there could be a halt instruction there, or worse) - it would simply flush the entire pipeline. The exact details may differ between different products, but the concept is very old.

The page walk case is a little more complicated, but there's also a mechanism here that would detect most cases of a modification during usage - look for 'TLB shootdown". Note that in some cases, both SMC and TLB modification during run are perfectly valid and serve a purpose (SMC is very often used for JITting, and page moves are a cheap way to pass data between processes without having to copy it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! For possibility 1, I guess I was thinking that instruction cache snooping would be confined to the current processor, but that shows you how little I know about all of this. For possibility 2, I'm not sure what I was thinking, but your explanation as to why it should never occur makes sense. Given your explanation, it sounds like when using cross-modifying code a serializing instruction like CPUID is unnecessary on x86 and x86-64 processors when the CPU supports self-snooping? And most modern x86 and x86-64 CPUs support this?

Comment: @Jason: I'd recommend reading the section entitled "Handling Self- and Cross-Modifying Code" in your favourite copy of Intel's developer manual (section 8.1.3 in Volume 3, for the version of the manual I happened to grab first - possibly a different section in newer or older versions of the manual). For cross-modifying code, you need something to wait for the update followed by a serialising instruction on the CPU that's executing the code being modified (or some alternative arrangement that guarantees the code can't be executed while being modified and is serialised before execution).

Comment: Thanks, Brendan. Ya, I've come across that section. I'm just trying to get a better idea about why that step is necessary and what the consequences of failing to follow the guidelines are.

Comment: @Jason, invalidating snoops are often a very robust action, clearing the line from the entire core. This is often meant to allow you to set your snoop filter (assuming it keeps the line for a while longer), so that other snoops to that line won't pass through to that core and interfere with its execution.

Comment: As for cross modifying code making serialization unnecessary - i'm not so sure, note that SMC is probably done on a line granularity, while most real usages would take a larger range. in that case, you might still want to maintain atomicity of that code area (although there are probably safer methods like marking the page as NX or something)

Comment: @Leeor, thanks. You might be interested in something I found. 

From http://www.mathemainzel.info/files/intelX6800andintelE6000.pdf:
"Software using unsynchronized XMC to modify the instruction byte stream of a processor can see unexpected or unpredictable execution behavior from the processor that is executing the modified code."

So even with snooping available, there are CPUs that could give you trouble if you don't execute a serializing instruction prior to executing the new code.

I'd love to force this behavior on one of these CPUs and see what sort of cross-modifying code causes issues.

Comment: @Jason, right, i'm not surprised. It's not just snoops, even with caches disabled and writing the code directly to memory, you can't guarantee things like atomicity for the whole code section, or even the page map changing during the write.